# Cannot set resoultion higher than 1024x768

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics

I did a fresh install of 18.04. I have an AMD A8-5600 (integrated HD 7560D) CPU and an LCD monitor that is capable of at least 1600x1200.

I only get 4 resolution options with 1024x768 being the highest.

I have apps that require higher resolution.

How can I set it higher?

Comment: Are you connecting the monitor over VGA (DB15) connection?

Comment: Doh! Yes I am.I'll switch to DVI tonight

Comment: Please add to question -- 1. Did the monitor work at the correct resolution in previous versions of Ubuntu?  2. Have you tried different monitors?  If so, what were the results?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'` and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: **RESOLVED:**   Switching to DVI cable solved the problem. I was tunnel visioned on drivers. The monitor only has 2 connectors; VGA & DVI and I was using the DVI for another computer sharing the monitor.  Thank you to everyone who posted :-).

Comment: You can answer your own question and share it with others @TheJ .